# Altium Differential Pair Routing Via to Via Clearance

Tags: altium, differential, routing, design-rules

In Altium 14.3 how can one define via to via clearance in differential pair routing to produce a different spacing between via to via and track to track?

I defined a design Rule: Electrical->Clearance->ClearenceViaToVia[IsVia,IsVia] to 0.2mm

Because my differential pair routing rule is set to MaxGap 0.15mm Altium violates it in interactive routing mode, which is pretty annoying
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you truly need the 0.2 mm clearance for vias in differential pairs? My solution would be to make a rule for `IsVia And InAnyDifferentialPair` with 0.15 mm clearance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the "InDifferentialPairClass" and "IsVia" clauses in Altium:

[image]

I haven't tested this, but theoretically if the object is a via and is in a differential pair, then it won't complain unless the clearance is less than 0.15mm.

Just make sure this rule has a higher priority than the original clearance rule (which is currently being broken).

Comment: Sorry @ThePhoton , Just read your comment. Didn't mean to steal it

Comment: No worries. But it's not clear to me if OP wants a rule that will make the 0.15 mm clearance not be a violation, or if he wants a way to make the interactive router produce 0.2 mm spacing.

Comment: I read it as the OP wanting to prevent it from showing as a violation, considering this statement: "Altium violates it in interactive routing mode, which is pretty annoying"

Comment: Yes, but that could also mean "the Altium auto-router violates the design rule".

Comment: He did not mention autorouting, he mentioned interactive routing so I made the assumption he was running the differential traces and changed layers mid-route to place the vias. It made the most sense to me, but I certainly can't argue. You could very well be right. I'd like to hear a bit more from the OP.

Comment: Okay, "the Altium interactive router violates the design rule, and that is annoying."

Comment: I need Altium to produce a clearance of 0.2mm from via to via but keep the 0.15mm from track to track.

Comment: Ah. In that case, I would just up the "max gap" in the differential pair rules to 0.2mm. I believe then the 0.2mm via-via clearance rule will take over, but as long as the preferred gap is set to 0.15mm then the traces will still be that far apart. Now, just a quick comment on Vias, generally it's good practice for the hole diameter to match the width of the trace and the outer ring to have a diameter 2x the hole diameter (i.e. 0.2mm traces would have 0.2mm diameter holes with 0.4mm outer rings). Otherwise your impedance will increase, and your current-carrying capabilities will decrease.